# Angular 2 setters vs ngOnChanges

Tags: javascript, angular

When you want to run some code after the component/directive inputs changes you can use setters or `ngOnChanges` hook, but what are the benefits of using one on the other? Or they are the same thing exactly?

```
  @Input()
  set someInput( val ) {
    this.runSomething();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
     this.runSomething();
  }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

One advantage of `ngOnChanges()` is that you get all changes at once if your component has several `@Input()`s.
If your code only depends on a single `@Input()` a setter is probably the better approach.

Comment: But if component has many inputs, doesn't `ngOnChanges` method become a place for several possibly unrelated stuff?

Comment: That's what I mean with "If your code only depends on a single `@Input()` ...". If the code that should be executed when a single specific input changes, then making the input a setter is probably the better way.

Comment: Nice answer.   So I understand that ngOnchanges will not be called when @input is used as a setter.

Comment: @kartik it doesn't matter if an `@Input` is a setter or not. If chamge detection updates any input, it will call ngOnChanges afterwards

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer any clues about effect on performance? It seems like
`
onChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.someInput) {
         this.runSomething()
    }
}
`
Should be about the same as the setter?

Comment: I don't see how this could have a notable impact on performance. If you have a situation where this is called very frequently then check it with benchmarks.

Comment: I don't see how this could have a notable impact on performance. If you have a situation where this is called very frequently then check it with benchmarks.

Answer (score 8):

There is one important thing in case of setter:
Props injected with setter should consider the matter of order

```
<child [item1]="item1" [item2]="item2"></child>
<child [item2]="item2" [item1]="item1"></child>
// not same if you use setter
```

So if item2 is setters, item1 some data and you use item1 in item2 it works fine because setter calls the moment value sets, once you change the input order in app template reversed, the app will crash hard because the time item2 is set, item1 is undefined..