# How to assign Angular @Input value into another variable and populate into the child?

Tags: angular

I have following parent html

```
<p>Parent</p>
<app-child [mainData]="mainData"></app-child>
```

parent.ts

```
mainData = [];
ngOnInit() { 
 this.myService((res)=>{
 this.mainData = res;
})
}
```

Child html

```
<p>My JSON {{mainData | json}}</p> //Here getting result from parent
```

child.ts

```
@Input() mainData = [];
myDataCopy = [];
ngOnInit() { 
   this.myDataCopy = this.mainData; 
   console.log('My copy Data', this.myDataCopy); // Doesn't get result on here 
}
```

If I need to process the @Input data how it possible?

Comment: Could you share the implementation of `myService()` with us? the callback indicates that you are working with some asyncronous here, which would explain why your code does not work the way you intend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it in **ngOnChanges** lifecycle hook

child.ts

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  const mainDataChange = changes.mainData ;

  if (mainDataChange) {
    this.myDataCopy = this.mainData; 
    // or, this.myDataCopy = mainDataChange.currentValue;
    console.log('My copy Data', this.myDataCopy);
  }
}
```

Comment: what you mean SimpleChanges?

Comment: `SimpleChange` class represents a basic change from a previous to new value.

Answer (score 3):

You can try @Input getter and setter

```
  _mainData: any;
  @Input()
  set mainData( val ) {
    this._mainData = val;
  }

  get mainData: any {
    return this._mainData;
  }
```

And read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577929/angular-2-setters-vs-ngonchanges)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe syntax depend on Angular version...

Can you try to force "bindingPropertyName" argument in @Input declaration ?

like :

> @Input('mainData') mainData = [];

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another alternative out there taken from [this blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creatively-decouple-ngonchanges-fab95395cc6e).

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-binding-methods-onchange?embed=1&file=src/app/child.component.ts)

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges  {
  /* METHOD THREE 
   * Using a decorator
  */
  @OnChange<number>((value, simpleChange) => {
    console.log('OnChange decorator methodThree', value)
  })
  @Input()
  methodThree: number;

}
```

### Decorator

```
export interface SimpleChange<T> {
  firstChange: boolean;
  previousValue: T;
  currentValue: T;
  isFirstChange: () => boolean;
}

export function OnChange<T = any>(callback: (value: T, simpleChange?: SimpleChange<T>) => void) {
  const cachedValueKey = Symbol();
  const isFirstChangeKey = Symbol();
  return (target: any, key: PropertyKey) => {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      set: function (value) {
        // change status of "isFirstChange"
        if (this[isFirstChangeKey] === undefined) {
          this[isFirstChangeKey] = true;
        } else {
          this[isFirstChangeKey] = false;
        }
        // No operation if new value is same as old value
        if (!this[isFirstChangeKey] && this[cachedValueKey] === value) {
          return;
        }
        const oldValue = this[cachedValueKey];
        this[cachedValueKey] = value;
        const simpleChange: SimpleChange<T> = {
          firstChange: this[isFirstChangeKey],
          previousValue: oldValue,
          currentValue: this[cachedValueKey],
          isFirstChange: () => this[isFirstChangeKey],
        };
        callback.call(this, this[cachedValueKey], simpleChange);
      },
      get: function () {
        return this[cachedValueKey];
      },
    });
  };
}
```

This method uses a [typescript decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). IMHO decorators are likely to stay but...

> Decorator are an experimental feature that may change in future releases

Answer (score 0):

app.components

```
import {   Component,  Inject,  Input,  OnInit, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public employeeData!: Array<Insight>;
  filterBy: any;

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes) {
       //To do filter
      // this.filterBy = this.employeeData.filter((obj) => {
      //   return obj.joiningDate === '2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z';
      // });

      //Assign Input Data to Var
      this.filterBy = this.employeeData!;
      console.log(this.filterBy);
    }
  }
}
```