# Angular - Wait for potential input changes

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have 2 components:

- One `child`
- One `parent`

The `child` has one `@Input()` and one `@Output()`. When receiving the callback of the `@Output`, the `parent` may change the value of the `@Input`.

Is it possible to wait for potential input changes after emitting an `EventEmitter` ?

Some code in order to reproduce the issue:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './app-child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() myInput: string;
    @Output() myOutput: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    public doEmit() {
        this.myOutput.emit();
    }

    private doAfterEmit() {
        // Do something with myInput - expect it to use the value updated by the parent.
    }
}
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    public theInputValue: string;

    public onEmitCallback() {
        // Update theInputValue
    }
}
```

**app-parent.component.html**

```html
<app-child [myInput]="theInputValue" (myOutput)="onEmitCallback()"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either a getter/setter approach or the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook where it looks for any changes to the inputs.

The getter/setter approach:

```
_myInput: string;
get myInput(): boolean {
  // can do other stuff too
  return this._myInput;
}
@Input() set myInput(value: string) {
  this._myInput = string;
  // do your other stuff (update the input value)
}
```

The `ngOnChanges` approach:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  // changes has other properties as well, like 
  // changes.myInput.firstChange, changes.myInput.previousValue, changes.myInput.currentValue
  if (changes.myInput.currentValue !== changes.myInput.previousValue) {
    // the value of myInput changed from previous, so do what you would like here.
  }
}
```

For your case, I would use the `getter/setter` approach.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577929/angular-2-setters-vs-ngonchanges#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=One%20advantage%20of%20ngOnChanges(),is%20probably%20the%20better%20approach.).